# Why do I have to use gets() function twice in a row?

Tags: c, gets

I have an unusual problem regarding the code below.

```
void Menu()
{
    bool end = 0;
    int n;
    while (!end)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        switch(n)
        {
            case 1:
                my_strlen_show();
                break;
            //other irrelevant cases 2-6
            case 7:
                end = 1;
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR");
                break;
        }
    }       
}

int my_strlen(const char *str)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (; *str != '\0' ; str++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void my_strlen_show()
{
    
    char tab[1000];
    printf("\n\nEnter a sentence: ");
    gets(tab);
    gets(tab);
    printf("\nWritten sentence has %d characters.\n\n", my_strlen(tab));
    return;
}
```

I have no idea why I have to write `gets(tab)` twice to get the program to work properly. When I use it once, `my_strlren_show()` function executes instantly and shows that the sentence has 0 characters. I am aware that I can use other methods such as a *scanf()* function inside a *for* loop, but I am curious why this method works in a peculiar way.

Can anyone explain why that is the case? I would be very thankful.

Comment: DO NOT USE `gets()` , it's dangerous and not part of C standard anymore. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Have you checked what `scanf()` actually reads?  Or even ***if*** it actually reads any input?

Comment: First of all, [you shouldn't be using `gets` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/11336762). Then: what input do you provide? Do you start with a newline? Probably the first gets just reads the newline character left by `scanf`

Comment: C has no function called gets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `gets()`.  Its dangerous unsafety has earned it the dubious distinction of belonging to a very small set of functions that have been *withdrawn* from the C language standard.

However, you would probably experience the same issue if you changed to `fgets`:

```
    fgets(tab, sizeof(tab), stdin);
```

The issue is that `gets()` and `fgets()` read through the end of the current line (or until the buffer is filled in the case of `fgets()`).  The preceding `scanf()` consumed only the bytes through the end of a decimal integer, leaving the rest of that line on the input stream, waiting to be read.  That includes at least a newline marking the end of the line.  That has to be consumed before the wanted input can be read with `fgets()` or `gets()`.  One way to accomplish that would be:

```
if ((scanf("%*[^\n]") == EOF) || (getchar() == EOF)) {
    // handle end-of-file or I/O error ...
}
```

The `scanf` reads and discards any characters preceding the next newline, and, supposing that the end of the file is not reached and no I/O error occurs, the `getchar()` consumes the newline itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `scanf` only reads a single integer from `stdin`. When you press enter after inputting the integer, a newline (`\n`) is sent to the `stdin`, which just stays there - waiting to be picked up by the next function reading from `stdin`.

The next `gets` then reads this newline and instantly returns. So you needed another `gets` to actually read the input.

With that said, you should never even use `gets` in the first place - it's a deprecated function. On top of that, consider using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) for *reading input*. `scanf` is really an input *parsing* function, not a reading function. It only reads what it can parse, and leaves everything else in the `stdin`.

If you still decide to go the `scanf` route, you should consume the newline on the first input using `"%d\n"` - not only that, you **must** also check the return value for `scanf`, it returns the number of values it was able to parse.

Now the next `fgets` call won't have to consume the left over newline. It'll wait for another line of user input (note that the newline will be included in the buffer `fgets` reads into)-

```c
char tab[1000];
printf("\n\nEnter a sentence: ");
if (fgets(tab, 1000, stdin) == NULL)
{
    // handle error during reading
    return;
}
// tab now has the user input, delimited with a `\n`
// if you want to get rid of this newline - use `strcspn`
tab[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0
```

Docs on [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn)

I would however, recommend you to go the full `fgets` route and do the integer parsing with [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

```c
int n;
char buff[4096];
if (fgets(buff, 4096, stdin) == NULL)
{
    // handle error during reading
    return;
}
if (sscanf(tab, "%d", &n) != 1)
{
    // parsing failed - sscanf should've parsed exactly 1 value
    // handle error
    return;
}
// use n here
```

Here's a full guide on [how to move away from `scanf`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) - which will mention this specific problem.

Comment: Note [the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string) — and do not ever recommend including trailing white space in a format string.  It doesn't do what you expect and forces the user to know what must be typed next.  A more sensible alternative is to read lines (with standard C `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`) and then parse with `sscanf()` or other functions, which you finish up recommending.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I completely agree. Though I believe, leaving a trailing `\n` on a `scanf` format string when the input stream is line buffered shouldn't be as harmful. But of course, `stdin` doesn't necessarily have to be line terminated.

Comment: If the input comes from a terminal, the trailing newline is a UX disaster.  It doesn't complete until the user types something that is not white space — something other than a blank, tab or newline.  If the input is inevitably a file, rather than a terminal, then you can maybe get away with, but it is still probably not a good idea.  If need be, the next input format can start with white space, but only 3 conversion specifiers do not skip white space automatically.  They are `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets), and `%n`.